# Silverstripe - Custom changes to a module

Tags: module, silverstripe

Not sure where to look for this. I want to make changes to a Silverstripe module I added to my site with composer but I don't want the custom code to be overwritten when I update the module at a later stage.

How can I make a few changes to some of the code without editing the core files? The code in question is in a function that is in a controller.

Answer (score 4):

It definitely depends on your case.

- If you want to add some custom methods use an `Extension`(see Simon's
  answer)
- If you want to add some database fields or relations, a DataExtension
  is your friend
- If the module is extensible and provides hooks, you
  can change behaviour in your (you guessed it) Extension. Look for
  `$this->extend('functionName')` in the module, you can modify stuff
  in a method `functionName()` in your Extension

But sometimes it's a
bug or the module doesn't provide a hook you can use, then you have
to subclass the class and tell SilverStripe to use your Subclass instead:

```
class MySubClass extends SomeClass
{
    public function doSomething()
        $something = parent::doSomething();
        //your changes
        return $something;
    }
}
```

You just need your changes and overwritten methods in your subclass, no need to copy all stuff in your subclass. This way you'll get most module updates later on.

Then you need to configure Injector to use your `MySubClass` instead of `SomeClass` in your config.yml:

```
Injector:
  SomeClass:
    class: MySubClass
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are some cases where nothing can be done at all, e.g. where the class you want to modify doesn't extend Object (or doesn't call its constructor) so isn't extensible, and is instantiated directly e.g. `new SomeClass` rather than being injectable e.g. `SomeClass::create()` - in this case (rare) you can't do much at all except PR to the module to make it extensible first

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own extension to it, e.g. `class MyModuleExtension extends Extension`

And override/edit/change code in there.

In your `config.yml`, register the new extension like so:

```
OriginalController:
  extensions:
    - MyModuleExtension
```

Comment: It's worth noting that extension classes can only augment the public API of a class, you can't use them to override any existing methods.